# pulling a python list out of a json object and converting it to something usable in C#

Tags: c#, json, list

I have a python server that sends a list of strings as a json object to a C# client. On the client end I have this code to deserialize the object:

```
try    
{
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var jsonObject = serializer.DeserializeObject(sr.ReadToEnd());
    textBox4.Text = jsonObject.ToString();
}
catch (Exception e){
    textBox2.Text = e.ToString();
}
```

What i'm getting as a result is: "System.Object[]"

Ideally I would like to put the contents of the list into an array.

can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I would recommend you to use Newtonsoft.Json library to deserialize json strings.

Comment: Show us what the actual JSON looks like.  Some of us aren't Python programmers, and don't know how Python renders a list.

Comment: When you call `ToString()` on an array, it will give you the type.  That's expected.  Look at the value of `jsonObject` in your debugger.  It's an array.

Comment: to dcg: cant get that library to work because visio2010 wont let me get nuget 2.12 for some reason.

Comment: to amy: it doesn't seem to be behaving like an array and it doesn't show up in the debugger

Comment: Then I suggest you learn how to use your debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an array of generic objects, however I supose that you don't want this and you prefer getting a more usable result, so:

Create a class with the object's properties (for example: id, name, etc.). You can use [this page](http://json2csharp.com/) in order to autogenerate the class.

Then deserialize the input into objects of the class that you have created in the first step, with the following code:

```
MyNewClass myNewClassList = serializer.Deserialize<MyNewClass>(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

I hope this can help you

**Edit**

This is a complete example created with the new information that you tell me in the comments:

```
var json = "[\"file0\",\"file1\",\"file2\",\"file3\",\"file4\",\"file5\"]";
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var files = serializer.Deserialize<List<String>>(json);
```

Comment: its just a list of file names, no fancy id numbers or dates comprising a larger object. i shouldn't need a whole new class for that.

Comment: @drako234 in this case you can chage `MyNewClass` for `List<String>` or use the generic object and use casting.

Comment: ok im doing that but it says "non-generic method cannot be used with type argument". List<string> listnew = serializer.DeserializeObject<List<String>>(sr.ReadToEnd());

Comment: @drako234 I have just updated the answer, I made a mistake: you have to use `Deserialize<T>` instead of `DeserializeObject<T>`.